# how to activate a given window?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

Anyone have luck 'activating' a given window (move to top with focus)?

Say we want to activate a workspace window in dev image (VW). This does not work?

```
| window main |
window := Workbook allInstances first.
main := window mainWindow.
main forceActive.
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want #raise, not #forceActive.

Answer (score 2):

Note that #raise will do what you expect on Windows, but

-- on OS X the window will come to the top, but not get focus
-- on some Linux window managers, #raise will flash the window icon in the taskbar, but that's it.

Comment: that's not good. Works okay in Windows, but best to also send 'expand' to ensure it's not iconified. window expand; raise.